# Approximating the central binomial coefficient

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $\ c\in \mathbb R.\ $ Let

$$ D_n(c)\ := \frac {4^n}{\binom {2\cdot n}n\cdot\sqrt{4\cdot n + c}} $$

Then, more or less by the Wallis product theorem, we have this well-known convergence:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ D_n(c)\ \ =\ \ \frac {\sqrt{\pi}}2 $$

This holds regardless of the choice of the constant $\ c,\ $ however the quality of this convergence does depend on $\ c.$

> 

**QUESTION**   What value of $\ c\ $ leads to the fastest convergence?

> 

I'd conjecture that $\ c:=1\ $ (I may even run some numerical experiments). This is due to my method from my other ***Question*** about the accelerating the Wallis product. On the other hand, by passing from the factors to their exponents (Euler's style) one may end up with something like $\ e^\gamma\ $ somewhere inside that constant $\ c,\ $ who knows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $$\left(\frac{D_{n+1}(c)}{D_n(c)}\right)^2=\frac{4(4n+c)(n+1)^2}{(2n+1)^2(4n+c+4)}=1+\frac{4n(c-1)+3c-4}{(2n+1)^2(4n+c+4)},$$
the convergence is the fastest if this is most close to 1, i.e. for $c=1$. In this case we get $$\frac{D_{n+1}(1)}{D_n(1)}=1+O(n^{-3}),\\ \frac{2D_n(1)}{\sqrt{\pi}}=\prod_{k=n}^\infty \frac{D_k(1)}{D_{k+1}(1)}=\exp\left(\sum_{k\geq n} O(k^{-3})\right)=1+O(n^{-2}).$$

Comment: Fedor, wonderful!

Comment: Thus now, in the textbooks, when they write about $\ \binom{2⋅n}n,\ $ they should replace $\ 2\cdot \sqrt{n}\ $ by $\ \sqrt{4\cdot n+1}$.

Comment: @Fedor: This is neat. But, I have a question: don't you think you flipped the $1+O(1/n^3)$ in the infinite product. Plus, intuitively, in $D_n(c)$ the convergence is faster as $c$ grows instead of for small $c$. What do you think?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I do not understand your question. What we do with O is, after all, only multiplying inequalities between positive quantities.

Comment: I think I understand now. On a different note, should $D_{n+1}/D_n=1+O(1/n^{3/2})$?

Comment: no, $(1+O(1/n^3))^{1/2}=1+O(1/n^3)$

Comment: Oops! That's right.